# NHibernate performing a delete with Cascade.All causes N+1 deletes

Tags: nhibernate

I have two entities Password and PasswordHash. Password has a collection of PasswordHashes (those are hashes with different masks).

When I delete a Password I want all associated PasswordHash to be deleted as well.

I did the mapping like this:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.PasswordHashes)
            .Cascade
            .All()
            .Inverse()
            .ReferencedBy(x => x.Password);
```

I expected the two queries to be generated:

```
DELETE FROM "PasswordHash" WHERE "IdPassword" = :p0
```

and obviously

```
DELETE FROM "Password" WHERE "IdPassword" = :p0
```

Instead NHibernate generated N+1 queries like this:

```
DELETE FROM "PasswordHash" WHERE "IdPasswordHash" = :p0 (N)
```

and

```
DELETE FROM "Password" WHERE "IdPassword" = :p0 (1)
```

How can I change this behaviour to be more optimal?

EDIT: Code that deletes:

```
session.Delete(password);
session.Flush();
```

Comment: Can you give the code that is causing the N+1 delete?

Comment: I guess this, with the code you use to perform the delete, might be of interest : http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-collections-oneshotdelete

Comment: Delete children with HQL (first trip) then delete parent afterwards? Also which DB vendor are you using?

Comment: What is ReferencedBy BTW (sorry for any stupid question) ? Does it change something when it changing for a PropertyRef ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that this was our extension method. It simply sets the KeyColumn to the appropriate value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my research, in the current release of NHibernate (3.3), it looks like it is not possible to delete a child collection with a single `DELETE` statement using actions such as `password.hashes.Clear()` or `session.Delete(password)` on your domain objects. The NHibernate documentation refers to [one shot deletes](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-collections-oneshotdelete) but I haven't been able to get this work with any combination of inverse and cascade for either unidirectional or bidirectional one to many associations.

One alternative is to use `on-delete="cascade"` which disables the cascade functionality in NHibernate and leaves it up to the database to enforce the cascade deletion. Further information can be found in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nhibernate-development/wE5gabvX-VE) nh users google group discussion.

The other option as mentioned by Rippo in the comment section is to use HQL. You would need two statements so it would be best to wrap them in a transaction, i.e.

```
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction()
{
   session.Query("delete from PasswordHash h where h.Password = :password")
                   .SetParameter("password", password)
                   .ExecuteUpdate();
   session.Delete(password);
   transaction.Commit();
}
```